# Can a developer create scratch orgs without a login on the Dev Hub org?

Tags: salesforcedx, dev-hub

Dev Hub can only be enabled in Production, right? At least I don't see an option to enable Dev Hub in a Sandbox.

My concern: does every developer need an active user account on Production to be able to create scratch orgs? Or will every developer need access to the devhubusername account? Can that account be an API Only user?

Answer (score 3):

I hope that answers your question

> System administrators can access the Dev Hub org by default. You can enable more users to access the Dev Hub org so they can also create scratch orgs.
>
> You can use Salesforce DX with these Standard user licenses: Salesforce, Salesforce Platform, and Salesforce Limited Access - Free (partners only).

[ISVforce Guide - Add Salesforce DX Users](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm)

Comment: It means YES and this is ridiculous.